# How to document a HTML node function in jsDoc?

Tags: jsdoc

I need to add a function attached to a node in this way:

```
myElement = querySelector('#myElement');
myElement.moveMe = () =>{
    //move Me Code;
}
```

But I do not know how to document this function (and also prevent lint errors), I tried use `@extend`s with a `@typedef` but it says that it just works with constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest that the right way to do this would be to create an object with `{el: myElement, moveMe: ()=>{}}` myself, but if you must extend, it looks like this:

```
/** 
 * @constructor
 * @extends {HTMLElement}
 */
const NewType = function() {};
/** @type {function()} */
NewType.prototype.moveMe = function(){};

/** @type {NewType} */
const myElement = /** @type {NewType} */ (document.querySelector('body div'));
myElement.moveMe = () =>{
    //move Me Code;
  console.log('dont remove me');
}
```

[Error free](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250A%250A%252F**%2520%250A%2520*%2520%2540constructor%250A%2520*%2520%2540extends%2520%257BHTMLElement%257D%250A%2520*%252F%250Aconst%2520NewType%2520%253D%2520function()%2520%257B%257D%253B%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bfunction()%257D%2520*%252F%250ANewType.prototype.moveMe%2520%253D%2520function()%257B%257D%253B%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257BNewType%257D%2520*%252F%250Aconst%2520myElement%2520%253D%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257BNewType%257D%2520*%252F%2520(document.querySelector('body%2520div'))%253B%250AmyElement.moveMe%2520%253D%2520()%2520%253D%253E%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252Fmove%2520Me%2520Code%253B%250A%2520%2520console.log('dont%2520remove%2520me')%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A)

Comment: Thanks, I need to extend the HTMLElement because `moveMe()` has to be accessible when getting it by `document.querySelector('.myElement').moveMe()`

Answer (score 1):

(Not sure about your stack, just noting my 2C from  recent (2019-Q1) personal **VSCode** JSDoc struggles.)

**In theory**, it seems it should be possible to use simple `@typedef` with "parent" type declaration: (**this does not work**)

```js
/**
 * @typedef {HTMLElement} movableElement
 * @property {function} moveMe
 */
/** @type movableElement */
var myElement = document.querySelector('#myElement');
myElement.moveMe; // NOPE, not present for some reason :(
myElement.tabIndex; // ok, this is from HTMLElement
```

Closest to intention of extending native HTML elements with custom properties was to `&` "Intersection Type notation" I learned about from [this comment](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1199#issuecomment-457227207) either using helper type:

```js
/**
 * @typedef movable
 * @property {function} moveMe
 */
/**
 * @typedef {HTMLElement & movable} movableElement
 */
/** @type movableElement */
var myElement = document.querySelector('#myElement');
myElement.moveMe; // ok
myElement.tabIndex; // ok (HTMLElement properties are present as well)
```

Or even without helper type, with direct intersection:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {HTMLElement & {moveMe: function}} movableElement
 */
/* ... */
```

Strangely, any `@property` declaration added to such extended type seems to be completely ignored (just like our property in the first failed attempt, I'm still not sure why).

---

I've been struggling to achieve something similar - extend HTMLElement with some hacky custom properties in JavaScript in VSCode - and after exhaustive SO / github / docs diving this workaround-ish solution quite worked for me.